# Match text between double or single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some regex help. I have been banging my head on this last few hours.  I need to match some strings in a minified file.

Sample string:

```
var a ='abc'; var b = 'http://a/that.dude.js/v1/'; var c = 'def'; var d = 'https://b/that.dude.js/v1/';
var basePath = "http://othersite/that.dude.js/v1/";
```

I want to match full text inside single or double quotes that contains `that.dude.js/v1`.  I tried:

```
/('|").+that.dude.js\/v1\/('|")/g
```

...but this matches the full line when there are multiple occurrences in the same line.

My expected match will be:

```
http://a/that.dude.js/v1/
https://b/that.dude.js/v1/
http://othersite/that.dude.js/v1/
```

Here is what I have tried: http://regexr.com/3cv62

Comment: [`(['"])(.*?that\.dude.*?)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/rN4dK5/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have single quotes inside double quoted strings, you need to capture the quote delimiter and use a backreference to match exactly the same trailing delimiter:

```
(['"])([^"'\s]*that\.dude\.js\/v1[^"'\s]*)\1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ4sD0/5).

Since you have URLs, you can safely match them with `[^"'\s]*` (one or more symbols other than `"`, `'` and whitespace). The regex matches:

- `(['"])` - the leading quote delimiter (captured into Group 1 so that we could match the same trailing delimiter)
- `([^"'\s]*that\.dude\.js\/v1[^"'\s]*)` - Group 2 matching

  - `[^"'\s]*` - 0+ symbols other than `"`, `'` and whitespace
  - `that\.dude\.js\/v1` - `that.dude.js/v1`
  - `[^"'\s]*` - ibid.
- `\1` - trailing delimiter that is the same as the leading one

The result will be in Group 2:

```js
var re = /(['"])([^"'\s]*that\.dude\.js\/v1[^"'\s]*)\1/g; 
var str = 'var a =\'abc\'; var b = \'http://a/that.dude.js/v1/\'; var c = \'def\'; var d = \'https://b/that.dude.js/v1/\';\nvar basePath = "http://othersite/that.dude.js/v1/";';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[2]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Note that to make it even more generic, you could use a *tempered greedy token*:

```
(['"])((?:(?!\1).)*that\.dude\.js\/v1(?:(?!\1).)*)\1
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ4sD0/3)

The `(?:(?!\1).)` token will match any character(s) but a newline that are not equal to the value referred to by the `\1` backreference.

Comment: sorry I didnt mentioned one use case to match var basePath = "that.dude.js/v1/";
var basePath = 'that.dude.js/v1/';

Comment: Glad to help. If you have further issues with this pattern, just drop a comment.

Comment: sorry. one more issue. it doesnt work here: var a=angular.module("mtaWebApp"),b="that.dude.js/v1/",c="1.0.6"; 

actually it works in your editor but doesnt work in http://regexr.com/3cv62

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, You can also use `(\"([^\"]|\\.)*\"|\'([^\']|\\.)*\')` for that, without having to do backreferencing (which is not strictly regular).  Making it regular, makes it more efficient scanning (one pass only) than including backreferencing (which is context dependant grammar)  In the regexp above i have included support for possible escaped `\"` and `\'`.

Comment: @Luis: I believe there are noescaped entities in attribute values, thus, it is redundant. Your pattern is not unrolled and is thus not that efficient as could be - the alternations inside capturing groups involve a lot of backtracking. The alternatiion on the upper level requires adding the obligatory part twice making the pattern much longer than when using a backreference and readability will suffer. If I were to choose between readability and performance in this case, I'd choose readability.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i'm afraid not, the finite state machine resulting from simple regexp compilation can deal with alternations without any backtracking, see Ullman's book http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811 (a classical one) for an explanation on this.

Comment: [Your regex does not work](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4pD3/1) anyway. You must have meant [`("([^"\\]|\\.)*"|'([^'\\]|\\.)*')`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4pD3/2). I say it is inefficient compared with [`("([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4pD3/3). Still, this regex is not doing what it shoud, and is doing one redundant thing. Go to the regex debugger page and you will see *lots of* backtracking steps. Mine (the last one in this comment) only requires 1 backtracking step as there is 1 escaped entity.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
/(["'])[^"']+that\.dude\.js\/v1\/\1/g
```

The only modification was to change `.` to `[^"']` this doesn't allow quotes between the quotes.

Comment: What if the double quoted "value" contains a `'` inside?

Comment: since it's an url, it wont.

Comment: If it is a URL, you can just use `\S`: [`(['"])(\S*that\.dude\.js\/v1\S*)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/gQ4sD0/2). Note it is not a good idea to use alternation groups with single characters. The character class is much cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but the results are not the expected one. I have posted my own answer.